# Upload and show word file in laravel 5.2 with phpword

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel

I'm facing a problem that I use `PHPword` for `uploading` and `showing` the content of `doc,docx` file with `laravel`. I searched and just find the way create doc file. So I need a help for solution for 'read and show' doc file with phpword. I upload file same like `laravel-excel`.
Here is my code:
+ upload form:

```
 <form method="post" action="doc/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="file" name="file" accept=".doc, .docx"/>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import" aria-hidden="true"></span> Upload</button>
        </form>
```

+ processing:

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file);

    dd($phpWord);
}
```

here is result after i run:
[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried to display the file contents yet? If not, make an attempt and post your code.

Comment: how to display the content, that the problem I'm facing.

Comment: please paste you result as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: @Preuk sorry about that, the result is the exactly content of `doc` file, but it too long, I just don't know how to show it into `View`.

Comment: Why don't you use the PHPWord methods to access that data.... specifically the ability to create an HTML Writer, and then save to `php://output`..... it always helps if you read the documentation and look at the examples for the libraries that you are using

Comment: @MarkBaker can you give me more specific or a reference link

Comment: [PHPWord Documentation](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [PHPWord API Documentation](http://phpoffice.github.io/PHPWord/docs/master/)  and [PHPWord example code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples)

Comment: thanks for your links but i can not do it